# Python middleware call on a particular request

Tags: python, api, middleware

I am implementing custom middleware which will check for the token authentication on every request that made . **i want this to run for every request accept one**

```
class CheckAuthorization(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        getKey = request.POST.get('authKey')
        if getKey is not None and getKey != '':
            try:
                auth = TblAutherization.objects.get(secret_key = request.POST.get('authKey'))
            except TblAutherization.DoesNotExist:
                response = JsonResponse({'Status':'Error','Response code': 107,'Message':'Invalid Request'})
                return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
        else:
            response = JsonResponse({'Status':'Error','Response code': 105,'Message':'Missing Paramters'})
            return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

**I Want this middleware not to be called for one particular request, hows thats possible**. if you can guide me to do the same any other way. i am new to python

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean one particular request? The URI is particular? If yes, you can add a check at the beginning of `process_request`. You can get the full path with `request.get_full_path()`.

Comment: yes, for a particular url eg: **www.xyz.com/users/login i want that middleware should not be called for this particular request** . if possible can you tell me how to add that to process_request ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore the particular url, you can add a check at the beginning of `process_request`, below is a sample code:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    full_path = request.get_full_path()
    if full_path.startswith('/users/login'):
        return
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a simple solution , didn't struck my mind

Comment: Hi Han he, could you look into other question that i posted. Waiting for someone to answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474259/django-middleware-making-post-request-blank/35476710)