# django middleware making post request blank

Tags: python, django, api, middleware

The post data that i am sending is captured as blank if i am using middleware, if i remove the middleware from settings.py file it returns the post data. what am i  doing wrong.

[image]

**Here is the correct result when i remove middleware**

[image]

**This is the middle ware code:** indentation might be wrong here

```
class CheckAuthorization(object):
def process_request(self, request):
    getKey = request.POST.get('authKey')
    token = request.POST.get('token')
    full_path = request.get_full_path()
    if getKey is not None and getKey != '' and full_path != "/users/splash/":
        try:
            auth = TblAutherization.objects.get(secret_key = request.POST.get('authKey'))
        except TblAutherization.DoesNotExist:
            response = JsonResponse({'Status':'Error','Response code': 107,'Message':full_path})
            return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        return None
    if token is not None and token != '' and  'settoken' in request.session and full_path != "/users/splash/":
        try:
            auth = TblLoginAuth.objects.get(token = request.POST.get('token'))
        except TblLoginAuth.DoesNotExist:
            response = JsonResponse({'Status':'Error','Response code': 107,'Message':'Invalid Request'})
            return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        return None
```

**views.py**

```
def splash(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        appId = request.POST.get('appId')
    except: 
        return Response({'Status':appId})

    gcmToken = request.POST.get('gcmToken')
    deviceType = request.POST.get('deviceType')
    userId = request.POST.get('userId')
    loginStatus = request.POST.get('loginStatus')
    appType=request.POST.get('appType')
    return Response({'appId':appId,'gcmToken':gcmToken,'deviceType':deviceType})
else:
    return Response({'appId':appId,'gcmToken':gcmToken,'deviceType':deviceType})
```

it's not even going in except when i used try except

Comment: The `process_request` seems to be right. From the screenshot, the json response had the key, but the value is null. That's to say, the logic entered the place where you composed this `json response`. Maybe you should check the logic of the view handling `/users/splash/`. You can print the response before it returns. By the way, do you have a `process_response` in this middleware?

Comment: i am printing the response at the start after reading the post parameters. what i learnt is if am using request.POST.get method in middle-ware it make my request blank and if don't use that in middle-ware it let my post parameters as it is . This is really strange, i am stuck at this and not getting any leads .

Comment: That's weird. The `request.POST` is  a `MultiValueDict` instance, it's an extended `python dict`. The `get` method doesn't clear the key and value. Maybe you can post the view code handling `/users/splash/`, and I can take a look if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Hi, please check the question, i have edited and added view.py

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when I was implementing logging middleware. It appears that Django removes all data from POST dict, if you trying to access it in middleware. Idk if it's a bug or feature, but I came up with temporary solution: you can use `request.body` to get the data.

```
body = request.body.decode('utf-8')  # in python 3 json.loads only accepts unicode strings 
body = json.loads(body)
content = body['content']
```

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. I am not sure, where should I use above code? In the middleware or view?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in middleware, but I know we use it in our projects and the key difference that I see is that you aren't returning a response on the successful cases. So I see you have try: auth = blah, but you don't use it. So you are always returning None or an error via HttpResponse(). What about success?

Comment: Yes, i understand that and will return none in this case also at the end which i skipped to post here. but the problem right now with this middleware is that both the if condition are false for this request which means it will go in else condition and return none  **so success case won't happen for this request**

Comment: But if you push None through, then where is your data going to be?

Comment: i don't need any data for the success case, all i need is to check in case of failure and thats what process_request does as mentioned in documentation. It return httpresponse or either none and in later case then it  proceed with request to the view

Comment: Ah yes. I see. I just took another look at ours and we are doing the same thing. I was looking at the wrong thing earlier. Did you figure anything else out since you posted?

Comment: nops, nothing yet. Waiting for someone to help with this. i don't want to put this code in my view